# Twitter bootstrap: do I need both bootstrap-sass and twitter-bootstrap-rails gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following entries my (Rails 3.2.13) Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

and in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

and at the top of app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```

Is this "correct"?  Do I need both 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' and 'bootstrap-sass' (or maybe 'bootstrap-sass-rails'), or are they redundant and possibly conflicting?  Do the 'bootstrap-sass' gems include the javascript for the framework, or only the CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to use SASS you should use [boostrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) or [bootstrap-sass-rails](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails). [Twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) uses LESS source. If you were to include both there would probably be conflicts. All of them include javascript for bootstrap already and integrate into the asset pipeline.

I personally use LESS version as it is what bootstrap is originally written in. (might get faster releases when bootstrap updates)

It's generally good to check the gems out on github to evaluate your exact needs and which version of Rails they support.

Comment: I accepted this answer because you specifically responded to my question about whether the javascript was included in the 'sass'-named gems.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

No you do not need both.

Just simply put this in your gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

This in application.css.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-responsive';
```

This in application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

If you're still having problems you may need to look at the ordering of things in your manifest files..

Comment: If you are using font awesome, check out https://github.com/littlebtc/font-awesome-sass-rails/pull/35

Comment: @Abram Thanks for your solution this helped me. Only adding the stylesheet was a bit different. For me `@import` in application.css.scss did not work. I had to add ` = require bootstrap` to application.css.