# bootstrap-sass with rails 4 gives error for responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I am upgrading a rails 3.2.8 application(contains bootstrap but isnt responsive) to rails 4.0.1.

My Gemfile contents are

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'haml'

#rails 4 doesnt support assets group. only test, dev n prod
gem 'sass'
gem 'sass-rails',    '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem "jquery-scrollto-rails"

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'uglifier'

group :production do
  gem 'dalli'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching' #use caches_pages in rails 4
```

Contents of application.js are

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

and contents of application.css.scss are

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "josh";
```

Its my first time with sass. My questions are

1) Are the gems related to sass correctly specified or are there any unwanted gems?

2) My application renders correctly(unresponsive) but if i add '@import "bootstrap-responsive";' below import bootstrap in css.scss file, i get error as

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Static#home
Showing /home/prasad/projects/website/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #31 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.
Load paths:
  /home/prasad/projects/website/app/assets/images
  /home/prasad/projects/website/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/prasad/projects/website/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/prasad/projects/website/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/prasad/projects/website/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/jquery-scrollto-rails-1.4.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/fonts
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

(in /home/prasad/projects/website/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:16)

I references [Twitter bootstrap: do I need both bootstrap-sass and twitter-bootstrap-rails gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256723/twitter-bootstrap-do-i-need-both-bootstrap-sass-and-twitter-bootstrap-rails-gem) but couldnt fix the error.
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @MaximeHeckel i didnt use any css.scss files in my application. i started using pure css file of bootstrap 3. BS 3 is responsive be default.

Answer (score 0):

responsiveness is native since Bootstrap 3.0. 
No need to add

```
    @import "bootstrap-responsive
```